# Which catalogue has identified objects from Gaia DR3?

Tags: python, star-catalogues, gaia, astropy, simbad

I am trying to match objects from a Gaia DR3 dataset having 1 million rows with simbad. I find it difficult to find object type for all the rows as queries using astroquery becomes insanely slow after 200 or so rows. Is there a catalogue with object type and object id from Gaia DR 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://cdsxmatch.u-strasbg.fr/  is the tool I was looking for.

[image]